# Do Dunder methods (magic methods) exist for `and` and `or` in python?

Tags: python

There's `__and__` and `__or__` for `&` and `|` respectively, are there modifiable dunders for `and` and `or` too?

If so, I can't seem to find them. They are not listed on the docs here:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

Context: making an api where I want people to be able to do `foo and bar and jar`, instead of having to do `method(method(foo, bar),jar)`. I can still use `&` and `|` but just curious, would prefer the readability of `and` and `or`

Comment: You can override truthiness: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: Don’t forget that and and or do short-circuiting. E.g. for and, if foo value is false then neither bar nor jar will be evaluated - that’s different from your method() would-be expansion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[PEP 335 -- Overloadable Boolean Operators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0335/) was rejected in 2012, with [rejection notice](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-March/117510.html):

> We've had many discussions in the past about PEP 335 and they always
> ended in non-action. I'm cutting any future discussions short and
> officially rejecting the PEP. Amongst other reasons, I really dislike
> that the PEP adds to the bytecode for all uses of these operators even
> though almost no call sites will ever need the feature.

Comment: Thanks, interesting to see python design decisions like this here and there for runtime performance reasons, when overall python is successful because it's a compromise for speed of development at the cost of runtime performance.

Answer (score 0):

No.

`is`, `and`, and `or` cannot be overloaded.